# Bitmap in an array Changing a Value

Tags: c, arrays, bitmap

I have an array in C of 256 bits declared like this :

`unsigned bitmap[8]`

I want to set specifics bits to 1, so usually I would do it like `bitmap[0] = 1<<2` for example which would give me `000 0100`, but what would be a good way of doing it if I wanted
the 34 bit set to 1 inside my bitmap ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well The answer to this question is

```
 bitmap[34/32] |= 1 << (34%32);
```

and comes from here  -> [bit-array](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/255/Syllabus/1-C-intro/bit-array.html)